# Word ribbon customization of native Office commands

Tags: javascript, office-js, add-in, cpu-word, word-addins

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to customize Ribbon in Word programatically using Word JavaScript API. I went through the documentation and couldn't figure it out. I'm also curious if it's even possible right now.

What I'd like to achieve is to disable one of the items within Revision Tab. There's a property on the Office object called Office.ribon, which provides requestUpdate(input) method, which should enable this kind of functionality. Although it looks like the RibbonApi is not fully supported yet in Word as stated in the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/ribbon-api-requirement-sets

Is there any alternative how to achieve this goal? It might be possible to do it in manifest.xml, but I'm not sure how to get the specific ID of that item. Only IDs of those top-level Tabs are documented, but not their buttons, dropdowns, etc. It also looks like it's only possible to customize only my own custom items, where I specify the ID by myself. Is it also possible to edit a state of those native Office components, like disabling a button within a Tab?

It seems like a basic operation which could already be a part of the API. Can anybody confirm that it's really impossible to do it so far or is there some kind of a workaround at least?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to programmatically change the ribbon in Word. We are working on enhanced ribbon customization, but I would not expect them to be available in Word before mid-2021 and they may not include the option of disabling a built-in ribbon button.